# Remove notification "Device is managed by your organization" while Device Owner

Tags: android, provisioning, device-owner

When I set my Custom DPC as Device Owner after provisioning on Setup Wizard, at the end of the provisioning, a notification appears. The title of this notification is "Device is managed by your organization". Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Do you know how to customize it or at least remove it?

Comment: Why would you even wanna remove it? I think this is critical info to know

Comment: I would actually want to have control on it so that I can change the information displayed on it

Comment: You can't. This gets handled by the google device policy app and it's a good thing not everyone can intercept this behaviour. and it's just displayed in the notification center, which you are not using a lot anyways.